# Counting characters in an Access database column using SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have the following table

```
col1  col2  col3  col4
====  ====  ====  ====
1233  4566  ABCD  CDEF 
1233  4566  ACD1  CDEF
1233  4566  D1AF  CDEF
```

I need to count the characters in col3, so from the data in the previous table it would be:

```
char  count
====  =====
A         3
B         1
C         2
D         3
F         1
1         2
```

Is this possible to achieve by using SQL only?

At the moment I am thinking of passing a parameter in to SQL query and count the characters one by one and then sum, however I did not start the VBA part yet, and frankly wouldn't want to do that.

This is my query at the moment:

```sql
PARAMETERS X Long;
SELECT First(Mid(TABLE.col3,X,1)) AS [col3 Field], Count(Mid(TABLE.col3,X,1)) AS Dcount
FROM TEST
GROUP BY Mid(TABLE.col3,X,1)
HAVING (((Count(Mid([TABLE].[col3],[X],1)))>=1));
```

Ideas and help are much appreciated, as I don't usually work with Access and SQL.

Comment: There's not a clean way of doing this in SQL. Your first problem is that the number of rows is defined as the number of distinct characters in all the values in column c. Are there any additional assumptions to be made about the data? Fixed or maximum length, Fixed set of possible characters?

Comment: Thanks for Comment popovitsj. I was affraid SQL isn't enough for this.
data length is fixed and characters can be anything.
I am thinking of making a VBA for loop.

Comment: Programmatically, it's rather simple, just concatenate it into 1 String and count occurences for each character.

Comment: the database has maybe million of records so I am not sure that would be good idea, the string does have a size limit and how would that behave memory wise.

Comment: @wvdz See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35766737/111794) for how this can be done without storing all the strings in memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Knowing that colum3 has a fixed length of 4, this problem is quite easy.

Assume there is a view V with four columns, each for one character in column 3.

```
V(c1, c2, c3, c4)
```

Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with Access-specific SQL, but this is the general SQL statement you would need:

```
SELECT c, COUNT(*) FROM
(
SELECT c1 AS c FROM V
UNION ALL
SELECT c2 FROM V
UNION ALL
SELECT c3 FROM V
UNION ALL
SELECT c4 FROM V
)
GROUP BY c
```

Comment: Thanks going to accept this as an answer, UNION ALL was exactly what I needed, my statement is working now. one more question, is there a better way t o extract characters from string than using mid() function and going one by one, I might need to use this for longer strings as well and the statements get very long and it is a lot of copy pasting. but Thanks, luckily no need for VBA for this.

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, doing it for longer strings will get quite tedious. Then you might start thinking about generating your SQL dynamically.

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish your task in pure Access SQL by using a Numbers table. In this case, the Numbers table must contain integer values from 1 to some number larger than the longest string of characters in your source data. In this example, the strings of characters to be processed are in [CharacterData]:

```
CharacterList
-------------
GORD         
WAS          
HERE
```

and the [Numbers] table is simply

```
 n
--
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
```

If we use a cross join to extract the characters (eliminating any empty strings that result from `n` exceeding `Len(CharacterList)`)...

```sql
SELECT 
    Mid(cd.CharacterList, nb.n, 1) AS c 
FROM 
    CharacterData cd, 
    Numbers nb
WHERE Mid(cd.CharacterList, nb.n, 1) <> ""
```

...we get ...

```
c
--
G
W
H
O
A
E
R
S
R
D
E
```

Now we can just wrap that in an aggregation query

```sql
SELECT c AS Character, COUNT(*) AS CountOfCharacter
FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            Mid(cd.CharacterList, nb.n, 1) AS c 
        FROM 
            CharacterData cd, 
            Numbers nb
        WHERE Mid(cd.CharacterList, nb.n, 1) <> ""
    )
GROUP BY c
```

which gives us

```
Character  CountOfCharacter
---------  ----------------
A                         1
D                         1
E                         2
G                         1
H                         1
O                         1
R                         2
S                         1
W                         1
```

Comment: Impressive, I didn't think of that one.

Answer (score 0):

It's a shame that you don't want to consider using VBA; you don't need as much as you might think:

```
Public charCounts As Dictionary

Sub LoadCounts(s As String)
    If charCounts Is Nothing Then Init
    Dim length As Integer, i As Variant
    length = Len(s)
    For i = 1 To length
        Dim currentChar As String
        currentChar = Mid(s, i, 1)
        If Not charCounts.Exists(currentChar) Then charCounts(currentChar) = 0
        charCounts(currentChar) = charCounts(currentChar) + 1
    Next
End Sub

Sub Init()
    Set charCounts = New Scripting.Dictionary
    charCounts.CompareMode = TextCompare 'for case-insensitive comparisons; otherwise use BinaryCompare
End Sub
```

Then, you execute the query once:

```
SELECT LoadCount(col3)
FROM Table1
```

Finally, you read out the values in the Dictionary:

```
Dim key As Variant
For Each key In charCounts
    Debug.Print key, charCounts(key)
Next
```

Note that between query executions you have to call `Init` to clear out the old values.

Answer (score -1):

Please Try this,,, I hope this will work

```
with cte  as
(
    select row_number() over(order by (select null)) as i from Charactor_Count
)

 select substring( name, i, 1 ) as char, count(*) as count
      from Charactor_Count, cte
     where cte.i <= len(Charactor_Count.name)
     group by substring(name,i,1)
     order by substring(name,i,1)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, Access SQL does not support Common Table Expressions (CTEs).

Comment: Nor does it support ROW_NUMBER.